# Change widget image button background color and shape

Tags: android, android-layout, widget

I have a configuration activity for my widget, where the user is able to select shape, color  of the widget and image src.

My widget has very simple XML layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/rounded_conners"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_color"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn03_off" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the src parameter is selected image and in the src of the image view is set a shape for example:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/background_red" />
<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
```

I want to change it programmatically according to the user selected color, shape and image. Unfortunately I can not solve this problem. I can change image button background/shape, color and image src in the activity. But I can not do it in widget, because I have no reference for image button, in the widget is no findViewById etc..

I can change the shape of the image view like this:

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.backgroundImage, R.drawable.square);
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to change the color of it. In activity I can do it like this:

```
((GradientDrawable)mPreviewImageView.getBackground()).setColor(colorId);
```

But I cannot do it like that if I have not instance of the image view.

BTW: There will be a lots of variations, so I can not make a lots of XML layouts and just change them based on user input. I need to do it dynamically.

Thank you for suggestions